# Why is my SSIS text logfile formatted in this way?

Tags: ssis

I have configured logging in my SSIS package by using the Text File log provider.  The connection string for the provider is the name of a file in my local file system.  The package completes and writes data to the log, but it is formatted in a way that I did not expect:

[image: Logfile as it appears in Notepad]

If I open it in Notepad++, it looks worse:

[image: Logfile as it appears in Notepad++]

Is this just the way it is?  Or is there some configuration setting in SSIS that I'm overlooking?  Notepad and Notepad++ aren't having any issues displaying other files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a unicode file but notepad++ says it's Dos\Windows ANSI in the corner. I wonder if the first two BOM character's got messed up.

Comment: You had it!  I had code in a .NET executable that was writing to the same file in a StreamWriter.  I changed my code to specify Unicode encoding when instantiating the StreamWriter and it cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured this is out.  The is ssis 2008.   I think if you put some characters in the log file first and then run the ssis package you have this unicode output, space between characters problem.   If you are having this problem, delete everything in your log file, save the file in notepad as "ansi" then run your package again and this time your text log file will look normal.  I think if you mix ansi and unicode characters, notepad gets confused.